# Emacs 24: Mode-Line Style

Tags: emacs, emacs24, dot-emacs, modeline

I am trying to change the styling of the modeline in emacs 24.

I want to add an overline and an underline. Underline works fine, but overline is not working for some reason. Here is my code so far (added to .emacs):

```
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
   :foreground "gray0"
   :background "cyan"
   :overline "cyan"
   :underline "cyan")
```

Any ideas on how to get the overline working?

Also is there a way to set the distance between the borders and text?

Thanks

Comment: For me it is working? I did change the background color to grey, otherwise I was not able to see the overline and underline anyway.

Comment: The underline appears to be within the background color actually.

Comment: It seems to me that the color of underline/overlines is being the determined by the color provided by ':background' even though it should take a string value if provided so that is another issue. But whatever I set the ':background' to no change. I am currently using the solarized theme if that is worth mentioning!

Comment: Try testing without using any theme, first.  FWIW, it works for me. I customize option `mode-line-buffer-id` to use a spec like this:  `((t (:overline "red" :underline "red")))`, so the buffer name (only) has both overline and underline.

Comment: Can you use both overline and underline at the same time?  Perhaps just use a box instead and set the border to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the default mode-line spec has a non-nil :box spec, so it might solve your problem to add the line `:box nil` to your code listed above.